# Simple Django-swampdragon + AngularJS real-time app

Tags: javascript, python, django, angularjs, sockets

I use django-swampdragon + angularjs to create simple django app which shows website requests in real-time.

All of the Django logic is okay, but when I try make it respond in real-time the system kind of fails. I think the problem is in Angular, since I haven't used it before.

So, the [django-swampdragon](http://swampdragon.net/) part of code:

```
# routers.py 
from swampdragon import route_handler
from swampdragon.route_handler import ModelRouter

from .serializers import HttpRequestSerializer
from .models import HttpRequest


class HttpRequestRouter(ModelRouter):
    serializer_class = HttpRequestSerializer
    model = HttpRequest
    route_name = 'activity-route'

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        return self.model.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])

    def get_query_set(self, **kwargs):
        return self.model.all()


route_handler.register(HttpRequestRouter)
```

The Angular.js part of code

```
// controllers.js
var ActivityControllers = angular.module('ActivityControllers', []);

ActivityControllers.controller('ActivityCtrl', ['$scope', '$dragon', function ($scope, $dragon) {
    $scope.channel = 'httprequests';
    $scope.datasource = [];

    // Subscribe to the activity router
    $dragon.onReady(function() {
        $dragon.subscribe('activity-route', $scope.channel, {}).then(function(response) {
            this.dataMapper = new DataMapper(response.data);
        });
        $dragon.getList('activity-route', {}).then(function(response) {
            $scope.datasource = response.data
        });
    });

    $dragon.onChannelMessage(function(channels, new_request) {
        if (indexOf.call(channels, $scope.channel) > -1) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.datasource.unshift(new_request);
            });
        }
    });

}]);
```

And, finally, my template part:

```
<div ng-controller="ActivityCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="req in datasource">
        <li>
            <span class="request_date">{$ req.date $} ...</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I run server.py and open browser on that url/port (http://localhost:9999/) i have this error (in browser):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1323, in _execute
    result = self.prepare()
  File "...lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2014, in prepare
    raise HTTPError(self._status_code)
tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found
```

And also this error on the console:

```
-------- SwampDragon ------
Running SwampDragon on 127.0.0.1:9999
DRAGON_URL: http://localhost:9999/
Version 0.4.2
Debug: True
Quit the server with ctrl+c
---------------------------
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET / (127.0.0.1) 206.58ms
```

And, of course, my page with request don't work either.

PLease help me find the error!

Comment: The previous answer got deleted, rather than converted to a comment. It was asking about whether you were trying to access the site on `localhost:8000` rather than `9999` as that is the port SwapDragon uses.

Comment: Nope, i access website as usual, on localhost:8000. I post error on 9999 as an additional information to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, you are running your django server and your swmapdragon server, correct?  As in you are doing both:

- python server.py
- python manage.py runserver